# Codeigniter routing segments/params

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$route['segment1/(:any)/(:any)'] = "myController/$1/$2";
```

in this case, I will have to link segment1/someMethod/someParam, but what if I don't have params in the url, i will need to write this:

```
$route['segment1/(:any)'] = "myController/$1";
$route['segment1/(:any)/(:any)'] = "myController/$1/$2";
```

thus the both cases will now work, so the question is: Can I write those 2 lines of code in one shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this:

```
$route['segment1/(:any)'] = "myController/$1";
$route['segment1/(:any)/(:any)'] = "myController/$1/$2";
```

is  duplicating,they do the same thing, use just one of them, i suggest

```
$route['segment1/(:any)'] = "myController/$1";
```

hope to be clear, when using this `"myController/$1"` you are saying everything following `myController/` should be routed, and it works also if no `$1` params exists.

Definitely use just one of them and don't scare about not having params, it works like a charm ;)